# Store result of minus query with multiple columns in a variable in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I'm using below code to fetch the extra Project IDs present in TABLE_ONE compared to TABLE_TWO (source [Store result of minus query ( list of varchars) in a variable in Oracle PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341473/store-result-of-minus-query-list-of-varchars-in-a-variable-in-oracle-pl-sql))

```
DECLARE 
  l_missing_id_list SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT project_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_missing_id_list
  FROM 
    (
    SELECT t1.project_id FROM table_one t1
    MINUS
    SELECT t2.project_id FROM table_two t2 );
    
  FORALL i IN l_missing_id_list.FIRST..l_missing_id_list.LAST
    INSERT INTO table_two VALUES ( l_missing_id_list(i) );
    
  COMMIT;
  
  -- Values are now inserted and you have the list of IDs in l_missing_id_list to add to your email.
END;
```

Now I want to add corresponding Project Names also to second table. Whatever extra project_ids present in TABLE_ONE compared to TABLE_TWO should be inserted in TABLE_TWO  along with corresponding Project Names . How to do it? Please note that I need to store the minus query result in a variable since i will be performing multiple steps with the result.

Comment: Why use PL/SQL at all? You could write a single query that gets the job done at once.

Comment: @GMB if there are extra Project_Ids present in TABLE_ONE compared to TABLE_TWO, i need to perform 2 steps : 1. Send an email with list of extra Project_Ids and corresponding project_names in table format and 2. Insert those extra Project_ids and corresponding project_names into TABLE_TWO ( question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341473/store-result-of-minus-query-list-of-varchars-in-a-variable-in-oracle-pl-sql )

Answer (score 1):

`SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` is just a list where each record has a single number.  You need to use a new record type to store the multiple fields in each row.

You could define a record type to use in place of `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`.  But I'd be inclined to move the `SELECT` statement to be an explicit cursor, so that you could define a new type as cursor `%ROWTYPE`.  That way, your record type and the select statement are always consistent, but it changes the structure of your code a bit.

Here's that approach:

```
DECLARE 

  CURSOR c_select IS
      SELECT project_id, project_name
      FROM 
        (
          SELECT t1.project_id, t1.project_name FROM table_one t1
          MINUS
          SELECT t2.project_id, t2.project_name FROM table_two t2 );

  TYPE l_missing_row_list_typ IS TABLE OF c_select%ROWTYPE;
  l_missing_row_list l_missing_row_list_typ;
  
BEGIN
  OPEN c_select;
  FETCH c_select BULK COLLECT INTO l_missing_row_list;
  CLOSE c_select;
  
  FORALL i IN l_missing_row_list.FIRST..l_missing_row_list.LAST
    INSERT INTO table_two VALUES ( l_missing_row_list(i).project_id, l_missing_row_list(i).project_name );
    
  COMMIT;
  
  -- Values are now inserted and you have the list of IDs in l_missing_row_list to add to your email.
END;
```

One note about the `BULK COLLECT` (both here and in your original post) -- the data you are bulk collecting is stored in PGA memory.  So do not use this code as is if there is a change the number of new records will be unreasonable (maybe more than a few thousand).